# How to create a handler in .net for export file from SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to perform some tasks before exporting the report from SSRS.

For this I am thinking to create a HTTP Handler and register it in SSRS.

Please provide me some .net code example to create a handler for file types and How to register it in SSRS?

Comment: Do you have integration services installed?  It seems like the natural choice for something like this.

Comment: I think we need more info about what the OP is trying to do before you could recommend SSIS - and is his requirements are SSRS -> web handler -> user, I don't see how SSIS would reasonably fit in there at all.  OP - there are plenty of examples on MSDN describing how to make custom extensions for SSRS - sounds like you need either a custom rendering or custom delivery extension, depending on what it is you need to do to the file.

Comment: I don't need custom extensions. I want to implement DRM as reports contain some confidential information. In our organizarion, We have an API of DRM which I need to call when user clicks on Export button. This API will add copyright info and some other info to file and then that file will be available to the user. 

For this I was thinking of creating a HTTP Handler which will handle  all the File Type extensions and call the API in Handler.

Comment: No answer for long time..